# Gijgo Datepicker previous and next month icon change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Gijgo Datepicker. i am trying to change the `previous` and `next` month icon to icomoon icons but i didn't find any solution to it. for the icon to the right in the input field, there is the option

```
    icons: {
        rightIcon: '<i class="icon-calendar_today"></i>'
    },
```

but not for next or prev month.

here is the sample code. i need to change https://tppr.me/V77Wu this to `<i class="icon-right"></i>` like this.

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
  iconsLibrary: 'glyphicons',
  format: 'mmmm d yyyy',
  value: 'April 11th 2019',
  icons: {
   rightIcon: '<i class="icon-calendar_today"></i>'
  },

  change: function(dateText, inst) {
   var date = dateText.target.value.split(' ');

   var day = date[1];

   var suffix = "";
   switch(day) {
    case '1': case '21': case '31': suffix = 'st'; break;
    case '2': case '22': suffix = 'nd'; break;
    case '3': case '23': suffix = 'rd'; break;
    default: suffix = 'th';
   }

   var altDay = date[1] + suffix;

   date[1] = altDay;

   var newDate = date.join().replace(/,/g, " ");

   $(".datepicker").val(newDate);
  }
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is with js simply. A way of doing it. Hope it helps. You could also use jQuery since you already use that.

It replaces the first element with the class 'glyphicon-chevron-right' here, maybe better to target it with jquery.

```js
var e = document.getElementsByClassName('glyphicon-chevron-right')[0];

var d = document.createElement('i');
d.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;

e.parentNode.replaceChild(d, e);
d.classList.add("icon-calendar_today");
```

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
```